# Using Deleporter for cross process mocking

Tags: .net, mocking, bdd, specflow

We are trying to use Steven Sandersons Deleporter tool for cross process mocking:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/09/deleporter-cross-process-code-injection-for-aspnet/

We are experiencing problems getting this to work, the same problem a lot of people have reported in Sanderson's blog post comment section:
"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted”

We have succesfully got Sandersons demo guestbook project to work. However we occasionally do get the "only one usage of each socket.." error. Recycling the app pool and doing an iisreset seems to fix this.
However, once we get past the socket error we get this error:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:38473"

Have anyone successfully gotten Deleporter to work?
This tool would really aid in our BDD development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “Only one usage of each socket address…” error was fixed in Steve's April 16, 2010 GitHub Commit https://github.com/SteveSanderson/Deleporter/commit/f9b9f3070ec99ddf0d11bb818decadbd46c1bf70. I've found Deleporter very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found that to get it working with IIS 7.5 I had to clone the git repository, rebuild the solution and use that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the samples Steve provides have a web.config suitable for IIS5, IIS6 or Cassini. If you're trying this with IIS7 or IIS Express, make sure you alter the web.config such that the module element is in the system.webServer section, not the system.web section.

This is all explained in Steve's blog post but I mention it here as it caught me out until I slowed down and read it properly.

I also found the binary in the 'Samples/ExternalAssemblies' folder didn't work when using IIS Express. But if I compiled the Deleporter project and used the resulting binary from that, everything was fine.

The 'WhatTimeIsIt' sample projects uses the 'ExternalAssemblies' version, so won't work with IIS Express until you replace it with a freshly compiled version.

Once it's working, it really is a superb tool.